# Is is possible to do a FragmentTransaction without setContentView?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm developing an Android app that uses Google Map API. I need to set a Power Button Key Listener and few flags for the window.

I've created a custom SupportMapFragment class and I'm loading the MapFragment dynamically in a FrameLayout.

The activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I get the activity_main inflated view through code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

After this, I've set the listener:

```
mainView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mainView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
{
       @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            //STUFF
        }
    });
```

And I've added the view like this:

```
final WindowManager myWindowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
myWindowManager.addView(mainView, viewParams);
```

I'm not using the setContentView anywhere in onCreate so here's the problem. At this point I need to load the GoogleMap in the FrameLayout through FragmentTransaction, but FragmentTransaction needs setContentView to work. This code:

```
FrameLayout mapPlaceholder = (FrameLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.mapPlaceholder);

if(mapPlaceholder != null) {
    mapFragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(mapPlaceholder.getId(), mapFragment, GoogleMapFragment.class.getName());
    ft.commit();
}
```

Returns this error when launching the application:

```
01-16 18:22:20.263: E/AndroidRuntime(7755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070018 (com.example.app:id/mapPlaceholder) for fragment GoogleMapFragment{b666a7d #0 id=0x7f070018 com.example.app.GoogleMapFragment}
```

Does anyone know how to use the FragmentTransaction (or add a Fragment) without setContentView?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using `setContentView`?

Comment: I need to display the Window as an overlay that hides all the buttons and Status Bar, and the user shouldn't be able to exit from the application (it's a sort of "tablet rent" project for tourism). So I need to set the app as TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR, and the only way to do that is to add the view though WindowManager.

Comment: What about using a DialogFragment as parent of MapFragment then you can handle the keys and we can also disable status bar ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: I've already set the immersive mode, but the user can still exit from the application with that setting.

Comment: The user can always exit any application, simply by clicking the home button. If you only want to disable the back button, then that can be achieved in a much simpler way, by overriding `onBackPressed()`.